# How to wrap an asynchronous function to avoid code duplication?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to avoid code duplication by wrapping this code in a separate function. Trouble is d3.json is asynchronous so sometimes an empty info object is returned. Is there a way to avoid code duplication here?

```
function getData(endpoint){

  //long stuff
  var info = {"succeeded": 1,"datum":[], "message":""};

   d3.json(endpoint, function(error, data) {

     //long stuff
     info.datum = data;
     return info;

  });

  return info;

}
```

Comment: Would you be duplicating code if you a) did all your general data initialization/preparation and b) called all your specific graphing functions from inside the d3.json call, where data is guaranteed to have been returned?

Comment: The thing is I'm trying to create a library of functions, each of which is passed the data so the data manipulation has to occur within each individual function.

Comment: Ok then, I thought you were pursuing something more like this [crossfilter example](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you step into the world of asynchronous calls you can never get back again, so there's no way to do this without making your wrapper function asynchronous also.  Something like this could work:

```
function getData(endpoint, callback) {
    d3.json(endpoint, function(error, data) {
        var info = {
            succeeded: 1,
            data: data,
            message: ""
        };
        callback(info);
    });
};
```

Your callback function would accept one parameter that would be your "info" object.

Note that I moved the info object creation inside the d3 callback function closer to where it is used but this is just a style preference.  You can, of course, put it back outside if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the one-way street regarding asynchronous calls. For my particular problem it would involve writing a bunch of different callbacks though so I'll have to weight that against the code duplication.

Comment: Passing functions around in Javascript is pretty idiomatic so it might not be as much of a problem you think to do this quite often.  It's just a different way of thinking that can feel foreign at first.  Look at d3, for example.  It accepts functions as arguments on nearly every call in its API.  And many of those can be invoked asynchronously if a transition is running.